# React-table - problem with rendering checkboxes on 'next' click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am working with [react-table](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table) and one of my column cotains checkboxes. I render that column with such a code:

```
Cell: props => (
  <label className="switch">
    <input id="for_all" className="input_switch" type="checkbox" defaultChecked={props.value}/>
    <span className="slider round"></span>
  </label>
)
```

But the problem is that when I click on "Next", checkboxes are not "marked" based on the their value in coresponding props (props.value), but it is kept the same as it was in the same row (in 10 row view, 11th checkbox will be the same as it was in the 1st row). How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved that issue by adding another parameter to the input field:

```
checked={props.value}
```